# 'useState' is not defined no-undef React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to use react hooks for a simple problem. I believe the solution is stupid but I don't see it.
I Tried to see in my package.json but didn't found the solution. and I'm pretty sure that I'm declaring my state in a good way.

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Chuck from "./gettyimages-83457444-612x612.jpg";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    joke: "",
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const result = await axios.get("https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random");
    console.log(result.data.value);
    setState({ ...state, joke: result.data.value });
  };
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-6">
          <h1 className="title">Chuck API</h1>
          <img src={Chuck} alt="ChuckNoris" />
        </div>
        <div className="col-6 searchJokeCol">
          <div className="card">
            <div className="card-header">
              <span>Search for the Phrase of Chuck</span>
            </div>
            <div className="card-body">
              <input type="text"></input>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <button className="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Just CLICK!</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <h2 className="subTitle"> Here is The joke</h2>
      <h4>{state.joke}</h4>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And that's my package.json

```js
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.0-rc.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "ej
```

and I get this error

> Line 7:29:  'useState' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: btw ,sometimes that error is when you are using a useState in a class component instead of function component

Answer (score 117, accepted):

You need to import "useState":

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
```

Answer (score 19):

I see that you have missed useState import.

Either you need to add like

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
```

or make it `React.useState` i.e.

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    joke: "",
  });
```

Answer (score 9):

You have forgotten to import useState

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
```