# React.js:useDef is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a React.js calculator app. So, as usual I proceeded by deleting the entire src folder and creating a new one to have my own elements in the web app.
This is the index.js files content

```
import React,{ useEffect,useState } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

And this is my App.js file

```
import React from 'react';

const App = () => {
    const [result, setResult] = useState("C");

    return (
        <>
        <div className="container">
            <form>
                <input type = "text" value ={result} />
            </form>
            <div className="keypad">
                <button>Clear</button>
                <button>C</button>
                <button>&divide;</button>
                <button>7</button>
                <button>8</button>
                <button>9</button>
                <button>&times;</button>
                <button>4</button>
                <button>5</button>
                <button>6</button>
                <button>&ndash;</button>
                <button>1</button>
                <button>2</button>
                <button>3</button>
                <button>+</button>
                <button>0</button>
                <button>.</button>
                <button>=</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </ >
    );
}
```

export default App;
And this is my directory structure

[image: directory-structure]

I'm getting this error.

```
src\App.js
  Line 4:33:  'useState' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

After going through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63705317/usestate-is-not-defined-no-undef-react), I tried React.useState in my App.js but now I get this error

```
TypeError: react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.render is not a function
```

How do I solve this?Is this because of the yarn.lock file like I'm thinking?

Answer (score 1):

Just update to `react-dom`:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `useState` hook inside `App.js` file but it is not imported:

**App.js**

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const App = () => {
    const [result, setResult] = useState("C");

    return (
        <>
        <div className="container">
            <form>
                <input type = "text" value ={result} />
            </form>
            <div className="keypad">
                <button>Clear</button>
                <button>C</button>
                <button>&divide;</button>
                <button>7</button>
                <button>8</button>
                <button>9</button>
                <button>&times;</button>
                <button>4</button>
                <button>5</button>
                <button>6</button>
                <button>&ndash;</button>
                <button>1</button>
                <button>2</button>
                <button>3</button>
                <button>+</button>
                <button>0</button>
                <button>.</button>
                <button>=</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </ >
    );
}
```